# Angular Material Data table catch sort event

Tags: angular, sorting, datatable

I want to sort server-side not client-side. so I need to catch the event when the user click on the header of a column. How can I easily catch this event and get the name of the clicked column as well as the asked order **ASC** or **DESC** ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `matSort` directive has a `matSortChange` event, which you can use to get the active `Sort`, from the following interface:

```js
/** The current sort state. */
export interface Sort {
    /** The id of the column being sorted. */
    active: string;
    /** The sort direction. */
    direction: SortDirection;
}
```

```html
<mat-table
    #table
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    matSort
    #tableSort="matSort"
    (matSortChange)="onSortChanged($event)"
    matSortActive="lastUpdated"
    matSortDirection="desc"
>
```